# Upgrade Nightmare - No Posts, Permissions Issues and Can't Create a new post

Tags: users, upgrade, user-access

Symptoms:

1. Can't view ANY previous Posts, but the correct totals are listed by class - published, draft....
2. When creating a new post - no save or publish button
3. Unable to administer ANY plug-ins - error message: You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page

What Has Changed?

Upgraded from 3.0.2 to 3.0.1 or something like that, I was clearly on 3.x

What Have I Attempted?

1. validated the roles and access values were correct for the admin user in database tables
2. Created a new admin
3. Changed admin user values to something else and back
4. Changed to default template
5. Disabled ALL plug-ins
6. Re-installed latest version

What would you do next?

Comment: "Upgraded" from 3.0.2 to 3.0.1?

Comment: Can I asked how you solved it? I have the same problem and I'm on Media Temple too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some problems upgrading to 3.0.3 on a multi-site installation.  I had used the automatic upgrade and it failed, but luckily, downloading and extracting the new files from WP.org and uploading them directly fixed it.  I would try that first.  If that doesn't work, try re-uploading your backup files.  *You did make a backup, right?*

Comment: I did make a back up ;)  This is solved, just figured out it was mediatemple specific.